# Node Sequelize where through multiple tables

Tags: node.js, join, sequelize.js

I want to be able to check to see if an athlete belongs to an organization when there are multiple tables in between the athlete and an organization using Sequelize.  Is this possible?  Or will I need to extend the association into the athlete's class?

For example, I have a structure like the picture below
[image]

As you can see, an athlete belongs to a team, which belongs to a division, etc... up to an organization.

I have a node/mysql database running using Sequelize.  I have used ruby on rails before, where you can use a "through" to indicate that an indirect relationship can be found through a particular direct relationship, but I haven't found anything like that for Sequelize on a belongsTo relationship.

Just thinking this through, even if there is a solution to do this, I'm guessing that sequelize will be joining all of these tables, which would be expensive.  Would it be best to perhaps just have the organization associated directly on the athlete instead of linked through a series of other classes?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sequelize, you can have nested `belongsTo`'s in a query. In your case it'd look like:

```
Athlete.find({
    include: [
        {
            model: Team,
            include: [
                model: Division,
                include: [
                    model: AgeGroup,
                    include: [
                        model: League,
                        include: [
                            model: Season,
                            include: [
                                model: Organisation,

                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

That's pretty ugly - but not necessarily a problem. The first thing to do is to try that and see if performance is a problem - there's every chance it'll be fine.

If performance is a problem, and you've got all your database indexes and stuff in place and still can't get to reasonable performance, then yes, adding the `organisation_id` directly on the athlete is OK. This is called "denormalisation" - where you store redundant data to optimise read performance. It's something you should avoid where you can - but when you can't avoid it, it's fine.

You just have to remember that when you change an athlete's `team_id`, you may also have to update their `organisation_id` too.

Comment: Although I didn't end up going this direction, the answer did help inform the direction I ended up going.  Thank you